# Extension for Google Chrome to display network accesses as Firebug does?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Is there an extension for Google Chrome that displays all requests and responses via network, how long they take and status as Firebug on Firefox does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use developer tools (**CTRL+SHIFT+I**) and select **Network** tab. Press the record button and then refresh the page you want to test.
Here is an image of what it looks like in the current page

[image: Chrome developer tools - Network tab]

If you need more details to help you identify performance issues you can download [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/). It visualizes metrics that are taken from low level instrumentation points inside of the browser and analyzes them as your application runs

You can install it from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl)

Answer (score 1):

There is a extension for Chrome from Firebug called [Firebug Lite](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench?hl=en-gb) which may be what you are looking for.

However, why not use the built in tools within Chrome.  Right clicking anywhere on the page and selecting "Inspect Element" opens the Developer Tools.

These tools include:

- Live edit DOM and CSS to master your web page looks.
- Debug JavaScript using graphical debugger with advanced breakpoints support.
- Analyze the execution time of all your functions to improve the speed of your app.
- Trace reflows and repaints as your app loads.
- Explore what is stored within HTML5 local storage databases.

Check out the official [Google Chrome Developer Tools page](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) for a full breakdown of features.

Answer (score 0):

No extension necessary.

Press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`I`, select "Network" and then reload the page.  This network monitor will also monitor ajax requests while you're on the page and can be opened into a separate window by clicking the small icon in the bottom left corner.